# OpenAI Whisper: occasionally doesn't start transcribing until restarting the computer

Tags: python-3.9, openai-whisper, transcription

I am using whisper to transcribe audio recordings. Sometimes, everything works well and the transcription proceeds relatively quickly but at other times, the same audio file won't start transcribing until I restart the command prompt or even more often - the computer.

When I run the transcription command (whisper xxx.mp3 --model large-v2 --language Ukrainian), I get no error, nothing, it seems to start running but no transcription appears, or sometimes, it appears but very-very slowly (like 20 seconds of transcription in 5 min).

When I reload the computer, the transcription usually works well again.

I checked the GPU performance when I run the transcription command and at both times (when the transcription works and when it doesn't), the dedicated GPU1 memory usage is 7.8 out of 8 GB while utilization is 0%.

When the transcription works well, the fans run quite loudly, but when it doesn't, they don't.

- GPU1 is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060,
- GPU0 is Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics.
- OS - Windows 11 Home.
- processor - 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-12500H.
- I have installed python 3.9.9, ffmpeg, and associated dependencies.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

P.S. I'm quite new to all this, so maybe there is something I do that is essentially wrong. So just in case, here is an example of how I would usually start:

```
python -m venv C:\Users\rusia\venv

venv\Scripts\activate.bat

whisper

whisper xxx.mp3 --model large-v2 --language xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Turning off "CUDA Sysmem Fallback" solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).